# How do I call two scripts in one html file

Tags: jquery, html, flexslider, prettyphoto

I'm new. I'm using PrettyPhoto Lightbox and Flexslider in one html file.  Whenever I put PrettyPhoto at the bottom of the page, right before the closing body tag, it makes my Flex Slider disappear and the PrettyPhoto lightbox isn't configured correctly.   I know this was answered before, but I don't understand the answers.  Could someone re-word it to me?

Below is in the html file:

```
<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly happens? What do you see in the console?

Comment: here's the link: http://www.runningonbroke.com/playground/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Concept Verification Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/rLn1f37L/)

You're most likely including multiple versions of `jQuery` - one version for each plugin - and that is the problem. You can use `jQuery.noConflict` or else you do something like the following:

```
<script src="jquery-for-plugin1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function( $ ) {
        //initialize plugin 1
    });
</script>

<script src="jquery-for-plugin2.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function( $ ) {
        //initialize plugin 2
    });
</script>

<script src="jquery-for-plugin3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function( $ ) {
        //initialize plugin 3
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I am. Let me give your answer a try.

Comment: Cool. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Running a script that uses jQuery before including jQuery itself isn't going to work.

You can't call a function before it's included.

Comment: That makes sense.  So that I understand what you're saying correctly: I can't call a function that doesn't exist in my html file, right?  I went ahead and tried to solve it this way: At the bottom of the html file below: <p> 
    <!-- Javascript -->
 <script src="/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<!-- Prettyphoto -->
 
   
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   ("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
  </script>
 </body>

</html></p>

Comment: No; you simply need to include jQuery before any code that uses it.

Comment: Do you mean the jquery library? or the jquery plugin? Include it in the head or the body?